# Spring Boot + Webflux + Reactive MongoDB - get document by property Id

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'd like to find all Offer documents by Offer.ProductProperties.brand:

```
@Document(collection = "offers")
public class Offer {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @DBRef
    private ProductProperties properties;
```

ProductProperties:

```
@Document(collection = "product_properties")
public class ProductProperties {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String brand;
```

Service:

```
Flux<ProductProperties> all = productPropertiesRepository.findAllByBrand(brand);
        List<String> productPropIds = all.toStream()
                .map(ProductProperties::getId)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        Flux<Offer> byProperties = offerRepository.findAllByProperties_Id(productPropIds);
```

But unfortunately byProperties is empty. Why?

My repository:

```
public interface OfferRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Offer, String> {

    Flux<Offer> findAllByProperties_Id(List<String> productPropertiesIds);
}
```

How to find all Offers by ProductProperties.brand?

Thanks!

Comment: did u try to debug? is the `productPropIds` variable empty or does it have value? secondly the retutn type of findAllByProperties_Id is a Flux. So unless u execute a terminal operation, you wont have any result. Try `flux.collectList().block()`

Comment: productPropIds works correctly, is not empty, the correct value is received

Comment: It should be `findAllByProperties_IdIn` I suspect. But why so complicated? Why not just `findAllByProperties_Brand` so you have a single query?

Comment: @Denium is right. You could just use `findAllByProperties_BrandAndProperties_Capacity` if you are using brand and capacity

Comment: Its rather impossibe, I get the error: Invalid path reference properties.brand! Associations can only be pointed to directly or via their id property

Answer (score 0):

After reading some [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/) found out that You cannot query with `@DBRef`.  Hence the message

> Invalid path reference properties.brand! Associations can only be
>   pointed to directly or via their id property

If you remove DBRef from the field, you should be able to query by `findAllByProperties_BrandAndProperties_Capacity`.

So the only ways is how you are doing. i.e. Fetch id's and query by id.
As I said in the comment, the reason it is not working is because return type of `findAllByProperties_Id` is a Flux. So unless u execute a terminal operation, you wont have any result. Try

```
 byProperties.collectList().block()
```

Comment: I'm still not able to get my offers by brand and capacity. I tried to get my offers by properties.id like that: @Query("{ 'properties.id': ?0}")
 Flux<Offer> findAllByProperties_Id(String propertiesId); but without success

Comment: did u try 'collectList().block()'

Comment: Yes, I use fluxResult.toStream().collect(Collectors.toList()); but still 0 results. It must be maye ralted to the ObjectId. My JSON looks like: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7a0a9c4313ec506f473595"),
    "companyId" : "1234",
    "properties" : {
        "$ref" : "product_properties",
        "$id" : ObjectId("5d5fc17b96764a5bfe152daf")
    },

Comment: I tried many options, including @Query("{properties: {id : ?0}}")
 Flux<Offer> findByProperties_Id(String propertiesId); From the shell works excellent: db.offers.find({"properties.$id": ObjectId("5d5fc17b96764a5bfe152daf")}) But I have still problems with Query in Spring Boot

Comment: Do you have the annotation @Id in your entity class?

Comment: Yes: @Id
    private String id;

Comment: can u put your code in git or somewhere where i can check