# How to get data with referenced object in Spring data mongo?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

This is `City` document class which i used.

```
@Document("city")
public class City {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String name;
    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private District district;

    public City() {
    }

    public City(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public City(String id, String name, District district) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.district = district;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public District getDistrict() {
        return district;
    }

    public void setDistrict(District district) {
        this.district = district;
    }
}
```

and this is the `District` document class

```
@Document("district")
public class District {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed
    private String name;

    public District() {
    }

    public District(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public District(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and this is the `district` collection data.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9482f3ff7ab743f0542070"),
    "name" : "Ampara",
    "_class" : "com.test.sample.model.District"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9482f3ff7ab743f0542071"),
    "name" : "Anuradhapura",
    "_class" : "com.test.sample.model.District"
}
```

and this is the `city` collection data.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d948333ff7ab743f0542089"),
    "name" : "Polgampola",
    "district" : {
        "$ref" : "district",
        "$id" : ObjectId("5d9482f3ff7ab743f0542070")
    },
    "_class" : "com.test.sample.model.City"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d948333ff7ab743f054208a"),
    "name" : "Porawagama",
    "district" : {
        "$ref" : "district",
        "$id" : ObjectId("5d9482f3ff7ab743f0542070")
    },
    "_class" : "com.test.sample.model.City"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d948333ff7ab743f054208b"),
    "name" : "Akkaraipattu",
    "district" : {
        "$ref" : "district",
        "$id" : ObjectId("5d9482f3ff7ab743f0542071")
    },
    "_class" : "com.test.sample.model.City"
}
```

this is the repository class for the above city document class

```
@Repository
public interface CityDao extends MongoRepository<City,String> {
    List<City> findByDistrict(String id);
}
```

in the city class, i have used referenced document class called `District`. this a another document. I need to get the cities which belong to one district. `findByDistrict(String id)` method doesn't return values. Its just returning empty `List`. So How can i do this ?

Comment: from where are you calling this repository method? what exactly is the problem u r facing

Comment: This method calling from CityService class. Problem is i'm dealing with the reference object of District. That is @DbRef object. in the repository i have wrote a custom method to get the cities belong to districts. but no data is coming out.

Comment: put all relevant code here

Comment: @pvpkiran i have update the question.

Comment: check this question and my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58165835/spring-boot-webflux-reactive-mongodb-get-document-by-property-id/58168309#58168309

Comment: Can you give `@Query("{ 'district.id': ?0 ") List<City> findByDistrict(String id);` a try?

Comment: @stripfire i have tried `@Query()` option. This is not working

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with another alternative.As @pvpkirn said, **You cannot query with @DBRef**. But i tried with `MongoOperations`. With this we can pass the Filter objects as Json object. Using this i got the answer. This is what i tried.

```
public List<City> findByDistrictId(String districtId) {
        final Bson filter = eq("district.$id", new ObjectId(districtId));
        FindIterable<Document> documents = super.mongoOperations.getCollection("city").find(filter);
        List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Document document : documents){
            City city = new City(document.getObjectId("_id").toString(),document.getString("name"),new District(districtId));
            cities.add(city);
        }
        return cities;
    }
```

in here i have used `com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq` to get the relevant `bson` object.